# php file_get_contents returns T

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents

I have a weird problem with `file_get_contents`:
I'm downloading text files from a URL with:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => 'Connection: close'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = @file_get_contents($source, false, $context);
writeFile($target, $result);
```

This works fine 90% of the time. However, sporadically the contents of the downloaded file will just be a single capital

> T

The fact that it occurs sporadically leads me to believe it is some kind of timeout related issue.

- Can anyone confirm this?
- Where does the T come from?
- What is a good timeout value?

Any insights are highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I have a similar issue with curl. Sometimes it returns nothing. I fixed it by counting the chars returned, if below <limit> then curl again.

Comment: I think it depends of resource that you try to get. I suggest you to use several tools like curl or some rest-client to be sure

Comment: @Andreas yeah thats would be nice to call again if less that the minimum limit, but if you are thinking about time out then increase your timeout and test again.

Comment: If it gets any kind of error, including a timeout, it should return `FALSE`. Maybe you should get rid of the `@` so you'll see the error message.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `writeFile`? What does it write if `$result` is `FALSE`?

Comment: @Andreas, thanks I might try that

Comment: @Barmar actually I just recently added the '@' because I thought it might be a returned error message. Also, I didn't post it here but I also have a line in there that emails me if $result is false. Haven't received a single email so far.

Comment: Maybe the problem is on the server, and it's actually just returning `T`.